# Update state object using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs

Very simple question but somehow I can't seem to make it work. I have this state and on a specific click i just want to erase values inside object.

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    fieldName: "test",
    fieldValue: "test2"
  });
```

I want to update the values to empty values like *{
        fieldName: "",
        fieldValue: ""
      }*. How should I?
I tried this code but didnt work

```
setValues({ ...values, fieldName: "", fieldValue: "" });
```

***Edit: my code works, I had another problem with the other component***

Comment: can you show the complete code

Comment: Your code should work fine, how are you checking that it works ?

Comment: Simply try this `setValues({ fieldName: "", fieldValue: "" });`

Comment: Sidenote: The recommend way to use a complex state object is with [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). The docs do say *`useReducer` is usually preferable to `useState` when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values or when the next state depends on the previous one.* which does seem to exactly match your use case

Comment: yep, code is ok, i  had another small problem. sorry its 5:30 pm :p

Answer (score 1):

```
import {useState} from'react'
setValues({ fieldName: "", fieldValue: "" });
```

tel me if it work or not

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need to empty the values in the local state, then try the below,

```
 setValues({ 
        fieldName: "", 
        fieldValue: "" 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({})
setValues({})
```

if u want to write the validation like `values.fieldName`, it won't throw any error, because the values.fieldName is `undefined`